# Not able to get firebase crash report from android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-crash-reporting

I have implemented firebase crash in my existing firebase app, as per the firebase document i have implemented but iam not able to get any report in my console.

Here is how I hav integrated

app.gradle:  [build.gradle(Module:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZg47.png)

project.gradle:  [build.gradle(Project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDIXp.png)

in my code I have added sample report code:

```
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));
```

I am not able to get any report in firebase console its showing the initial page

I have updated the google play service even thought not able to get the report

Comment: Run your app in your actual device which has installed latest google play servicesl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firebase analytics don't work in real time it takes around 2-3 hours to update analytics data in the console. don't why but we observe this when we implemented firebase analytics
>   [for more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events)
>
> try this

```
android {

 defaultConfig {

     versionCode 1
 }
```

}

Comment: Now iam getting this error in logcat   Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Invalid package version number.